# Eigenvalues of matrix satisfying $A^2 = A$

Tags: linear-algebra

I would be very grateful if someone can help me with the following assignment:

I'm given an $n\times n$ matrix $A$.

If $A \neq I,0$ and $A = A^2$, I need to prove that $\lambda=0$ and $\lambda=1$ are $A$'s eigenvalues and that they are $A$'s only eigenvalues.

Comment: Look at elements like $w= Av-v$. Enjoy calcula.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose $\;0\neq v\in V\; $ is an eigenvector of $\;A\;$with eigenvalue $\;\lambda\;$ , then

$$\lambda v= Av=A^2v=A(\lambda v)=\lambda Av=\lambda^2v$$

So

$$(\lambda^2-\lambda)v=0\implies \lambda^2=\lambda\iff \lambda=0,1$$

$\;A\;$ is a zero of $\;x^2-x\;$ , which means this is the matrix's minimal polynomial (why?), and thus the above two are indeed eigenvalues of $\;A\;$

Comment: This only addresses the fact that $0$ and $1$ are the only possible eigenvalues; it does not prove that $A$ in fact has those eigenvalues...

Comment: I was trying to reach an explanation avoiding the minimal polynomial, as it may be advanced stuff for someone asking this question, yet I couldn't find it. So I added the minimal polynomial explanation.

Comment: Another argument that avoids the minimal polynomial: If $A$ were invertible, then multiplying $A^2 = A$ by $A^{-1}$ we get $A = I$, a contradiction. Therefore $A$ is not invertible, so $0$ is an eigenvalue. If $0$ is its only eigenvalue, then $A$ is nilpotent, so $A^n = 0$ for some positive integer $n$. But it's an easy induction to show that $A^2 = A$ implies $A^n = A$, so $A = 0$, a contradiction. Therefore $0$ is not the only eigenvalue. By the above answer, $1$ must also be an eigenvalue.

Comment: Bungo your comment fails to take into account that the identity is also a projection, ie. $I^2=I$.

Comment: @Ukhrir, I don't think so: the OP mentions that $\;A\neq I\;$ .

Comment: Ah, I simply overlooked that. Then all's good

Comment: @Bungo [years later].  +1. Here is a slightly simpler argument for existence of evalue 1 (without using nilpotent property): If $A\neq 0$ then there is an $x$ such that $Ax \neq 0$, and so $Ax$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue 1.

Comment: @Michael Nice observation!

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $A$ were invertible. Then, $$A^2 = A \implies A^2 \cdot A^{-1} = A\cdot A^{-1} \implies A = I,$$
contrary to our hypothesis. Therefore, $A$ is not invertible and so $\det A = 0$. Since the determinant is the product of eigenvalues, $A$ must have $0$ as an eigenvalue.

Suppose $\lambda = 0$ were the only eigenvalue. Then $(A-I)v \neq 0$ for all non-zero $v$ and hence $A-I$ is full rank. But since $A^2=A$, we have $(A-I)A = A^2-A = 0$, so every column of $A$ is in the null space of $A-I$, implying that $A = 0$, which contradicts our hypothesis.